# Python Tkinter: _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Here is my class, trying to make an image viewer split into 4 frames, each of which is displaying an image, the four frames belong to `root`, each `Frame` widget's child is a label containing an image.
each image is resized inside the `resize_image(img_path)` function in order to fit the parent frame dimensions, it is then passed to `show_image(resize_image, frame_x)`.
When I run my code I get the traceback below, what am I missing please?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/EM/Desktop/Scripts/gui/slideshow_model/slide_show_class.py", line 62, in <module>
    slideshow_model.show_image(img1, slideshow_model.frame_1)
  File "c:/Users/EM/Desktop/Scripts/gui/slideshow_model/slide_show_class.py", line 52, in show_image
    label = tk.Label(frame_x, image=image, background="black", bd=0)
  File "C:\Users\EM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2763, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\EM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

My code:

```
class SlideshowModel(tk.Tk, tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('Basic Image Viewer')
        self.root.iconbitmap('../img/favicon.ico')
        self.root.state('zoomed')
        self.s_w = int(self.root.winfo_screenwidth())
        self.s_h = int(self.root.winfo_screenheight())
        self.grid_w = self.s_w // 2
        self.grid_h = self.s_h // 2
        self.frame_1 = tk.Frame(self.root, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.frame_2 = tk.Frame(self.root, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_2.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.frame_3 = tk.Frame(self.root, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_3.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.frame_4 = tk.Frame(self.root, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_4.grid(column=1, row=1)

    # show image function
    # should contain grid coordinates
    # image dimensions calculator
    # remember anti-aliasing

    # should return the image object
    def resize_image(self, img_path):
        image = Image.open(img_path)
        w_coeff = image.width / self.grid_w
        h_coeff = image.height / self.grid_h
        w_coeff = 1 / w_coeff if w_coeff > 1 else w_coeff
        h_coeff = 1 / h_coeff if h_coeff > 1 else h_coeff
        # pick the smallest coeff to get the image as small
        # as should be
        coeff = min(w_coeff, h_coeff)
        image = image.resize(
            (int(image.width * coeff), int(image.height * coeff)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        return image

    # this function should show returned image
    # takes: image object, master frame
    def show_image(self, resize_image, frame_x):
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image)
        label = tk.Label(frame_x, image=image, background="black", bd=0)


slideshow_model = SlideshowModel()

img1 = slideshow_model.resize_image('../img/sample.jpg')
img2 = slideshow_model.resize_image('../img/sample.jpg')
img3 = slideshow_model.resize_image('../img/sample.jpg')
img4 = slideshow_model.resize_image('../img/sample.jpg')

slideshow_model.show_image(img1, slideshow_model.frame_1)
slideshow_model.show_image(img2, slideshow_model.frame_2)
slideshow_model.show_image(img3, slideshow_model.frame_3)
slideshow_model.show_image(img4, slideshow_model.frame_4)

SlideshowModel.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should almost always have only a single root window. You have two in the code you posted. You should inherit from `Tk` **or** create an instance, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts, removed root and placed at the bottom to make code look alittle cleaner, pyimage couldn't be found so i used pillow modules and dir to locate ico photo on my desktop by using **r**'C:', when i run this code now, works only for a sec than deletes. don't think this is part of the code but wen it does display i see my icon on the corner, code also doesn't give me an error for the unused variable 'label'. u can block it without cause trouble to the code, u can get rid of most of this code by using geometry and using lists for img's.. new to stack overflow so hope i answerd ur question XD

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class SlideshowModel(tk.Tk, tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master= None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hand.ico')
        self.state('zoomed')
        self.s_w = int(self.winfo_screenwidth())
        self.s_h = int(self.winfo_screenheight())
        self.grid_w = self.s_w // 2
        self.grid_h = self.s_h // 2

        self.frame_1 = tk.Frame(self, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        
        self.frame_2 = tk.Frame(self, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_2.grid(column=1, row=0)

        self.frame_3 = tk.Frame(self, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_3.grid(column=0, row=1)

        self.frame_4 = tk.Frame(self, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_4.grid(column=1, row=1)

    # show image function
    # should contain grid coordinates
    # image dimensions calculator
    # remember anti-aliasing

    # should return the image object
    def resize_image(self, img_path):
        image = Image.open(img_path)
        w_coeff = image.width / self.grid_w
        h_coeff = image.height / self.grid_h
        w_coeff = 1 / w_coeff if w_coeff > 1 else w_coeff
        h_coeff = 1 / h_coeff if h_coeff > 1 else h_coeff
        # pick the smallest coeff to get the image as small
        # as should be
        coeff = min(w_coeff, h_coeff)
        image = image.resize(
            (int(image.width * coeff), int(image.height * coeff)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        return image

    # this function should show returned image
    # takes: image object, master frame
    def show_image(self, resize_image, frame_x):
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image)
        label = tk.Label(frame_x, image=image, background="black", bd=0)


slideshow_model = SlideshowModel()

img1 = slideshow_model.resize_image(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hand.ico')
img2 = slideshow_model.resize_image(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hand.ico')
img3 = slideshow_model.resize_image(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hand.ico')
img4 = slideshow_model.resize_image(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hand.ico')

slideshow_model.show_image(img1, slideshow_model.frame_1)
slideshow_model.show_image(img2, slideshow_model.frame_2)
slideshow_model.show_image(img3, slideshow_model.frame_3)
slideshow_model.show_image(img4, slideshow_model.frame_4)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Basic Image Viewer')
    root.label.pack()
    SlideshowModel.mainloop()
main
```