# Why does the error `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist` occur only when I call my function from a different file?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I am writing an image cropper from scratch for my project. I am using Pillow (PIL) as the image manipulation library and tkinter for the GUI

I have a function that uses tkinter to show an image as a preview in a window. The code runs fine when run directly from the file,

but when I call the file in my `main.py` file, on this particular line:

```py
self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=self.tk_image)
```

I get this error: `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`

the error occurs in this block of code:

```py
# img_proc/image_cropper.py
from tkinter import TOP, Button, Canvas, Label, Tk
from typing import Optional

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class CropperCanvas:

    def __init__(self, tk_root: Tk, image: Image.Image):
        self.canvas: Canvas = Canvas(tk_root, width=image.width, height=image.height)
        self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        # the break in the debugger occurs here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=self.tk_image)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.start_x: int = 0
        self.start_y: int = 0
        self.rect_id: Optional[int] = None
```

this class itself is initialized when it is called for instantiating the following class:

```py
# img_proc/image_cropper.py
class ImageCropperUI:
    def __init__(self, tk_root: Tk, image: Image.Image) -> None:
        self.root: Tk = tk_root
        self.root.title("Image Cropper")

        self.image: Image.Image = image

        # CropperCanvas is called on this line vvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.canvas_handler = CropperCanvas(tk_root, image)

        self.canvas_handler.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_press)
        self.canvas_handler.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_drag)
        self.canvas_handler.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_release)

        self.confirm_preview_button: Button = Button(
            tk_root, text="Confirm Preview", command=self.confirm_preview
        )
        self.confirm_preview_button.pack(side=TOP)

        self.confirm_crop_button: Button = Button(
            tk_root, text="Confirm Crop", command=self.confirm_crop
        )
        self.confirm_crop_button.pack(side=TOP)
        self.confirm_crop_button["state"] = "disabled"

        self.cropped_image: Optional[Image.Image] = None
        self.preview_tk_image: Optional[ImageTk.PhotoImage] = None

        self.preview_label: Optional[Label] = None
```

What's the cause of this error when called from main.py but not when cropper.py is run directly?

For further context, this is my main.py file:

```py
# main.py
"""
Main program
"""

import logging
import os
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import Tk

from PIL import Image

import img_select
from img_proc import cropper


def main() -> None:
    """
    Main function
    No parameters. Returns None.
    """
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    input_image = img_select.select()

    if input_image:
        root = Tk()
        img = Image.open(str(input_image))

        # error here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        crop_GUI = cropper.ImageCropperUI(root, img)
        if Path("cropped.png").is_file():
            os.remove("cropped.png")
        if crop_GUI.cropped_image:
            crop_GUI.cropped_image.save("cropped.png")
            logging.debug("Cropped image saved to 'cropped.png'")
        img.close()

        logging.debug("showing cropped image")

        if Path("cropped.png").is_file():
            with Image.open("cropped.png") as img:
                img.show()

        root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I expect the main() function to use the cropping window in the same way that cropper.py does.

However, I am getting the error `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist` when the cropping feature is called from main.py

I'd like to know why this is happening only for calls outside the module and how to fix it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518210/python-tkinter-tkinter-tclerror-image-pyimage1-doesnt-exist . Since you can run your code by itself, I guess there's also a main loop there, and you may have two conflicting main loops. Can't tell, because the relevant code isn't show.

Comment: It is better to provide relevant code of `img_select` module because the issue cannot be reproduced if `input_image` is hard-coded.

Comment: Sure thing! @acw1668
Here's img_select: https://pastebin.com/rZ4RUS4R

It's at the root of the project, and hasn't been given its own module yet

Comment: You don't need to create the hidden window inside `select()` because it is the cause of the issue.

Comment: Why are you using so many  file open library? You can only used one file open.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I was indeed running an existing root.mainloop() in the ImageCropperUI object, which caused my code to run into faults, as mentioned

Removing the mainloop from the ImageCropperUI and moving it to a manual call in main() fixed it!